# How to make the regular expression match excat zip code only?

Tags: java, regex

I need to have a regular expression which matches the exact code .
As of now , I have this code

```
public class Test {
    
      private static final String ZIP_REGEX = "([0-9]{5})";
      private static final Pattern ZIP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ZIP_REGEX);
      
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = " CVV:234,SSN:123456789,productPrice:23445.567";
            Matcher matcher = ZIP_PATTERN.matcher(str);
            boolean b =    matcher.find();
            System.out.println(b); // prints true 
    }
}
```

right now its prinitng true for an SSN also and productPrice also

The valid zip code is 5 digit number  53001 , so it should print false , as there is no zip  code in the string provided

Comment: Where is the ZIP code in your string, `CVV:234,SSN:123456789,productPrice:23445.567`?

Comment: The zip code is 5 digit number  53001 , so as there is no zipcode , it should print false

Comment: Then, post a string which has ZIP code.

Comment: `"ZIP:\\d{5,5}"` should do it…

Comment: How would you determine that these 5-digit strings are not zip codes?

Comment: because the length is more than 5 digits

Comment: Does `ZIP:` stand in front of the ZIP code? If not, You must exclude longer numbers explicitly with eg. `"\\d{5,5}(?!\\d)"`.

Comment: @Marvin Your example is for Javascript. You tested it with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?<![.\d])([1-9]{1}[0-9]{4})(?![.\d])` which can be described as follows:

1. `(?<![.\d])` specifies Negative Lookbehind for a dot or a digit i.e. `[.\d]`
2. `([1-9]{1}[0-9]{4})` specifies a digit from 1 to 9 followed by 4 digits from 0 to 9. If the ZIP code can start with 0, you can simply use `([0-9]{5})`.
3. `(?![.\d])` specifies Negative Lookahead for a dot or a digit i.e. `[.\d]`

Learn more about it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yxK4ag/1).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    private static final String ZIP_REGEX = "(?<![.\\d])([1-9]{1}[0-9]{4})(?![.\\d])";
    private static final Pattern ZIP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ZIP_REGEX);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(hasZipCode("CVV:234,SSN:123456789,productPrice:23445.567"));
        System.out.println(hasZipCode("A12345CVV:234,SSN:123456789,productPrice:23445.567"));
    }

    static boolean hasZipCode(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = ZIP_PATTERN.matcher(str);
        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but the string will be not precceded with ZIP: , it will be just a five digit number only

Comment: At least in my country zip codes can start with a `0`.

Comment: @Marvin - In that case, instead of `([1-9]{1}[0-9]{4})`, only `([0-9]{5})` will do the job. Thanks for your feedback...just for my knowledge, if you don't mind, may I ask which country you are from?

Comment: @Marvin - Thanks for the information. Much appreciated! It's good to know about different systems. I am from the UK and here the postcode starts with a letter e.g. `LU2 9TN`. By the way,  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use below regex with `Caret(^)` at beginning and `$` followed by limit, which imposes condition from start of the line and to be exact length of 5

```
private static final String ZIP_REGEX = "^([0-9]){5}$";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the exact String "53001" and don't care if its preceded or succeeded by other characters, you RegEx should simply be `53001`.

Tip: try https://regexr.com/ to evaluate your RegEx's. I use it a lot.

Comment: its not exact 53001 , it can be any number of  5 digits without decimals

Comment: length is 5 digits , no decimals .

Comment: Can you give an example that should render to true upon evaluation?